# Qual é o uso desses colchetes em C?

Tags: c, windows, sintaxe

Eu estava olhando o o `windows.h` e encontrei esse pedaço de código:

```
#define _SA_annotes3(n,pp1,pp2,pp3)    [SAL_annotes(Name=#n, p1=_SA_SPECSTRIZE(pp1), p2=_SA_SPECSTRIZE(pp2), p3=_SA_SPECSTRIZE(pp3))]
```

O que é o uso desses colchetes? Eles parecem meio soltos.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Esta é uma extensão da Microsoft, então não funciona em outros compiladores.

É algo usado para dar mais informações de como o código deve se comportar e permitir que alguma ferramenta mais específica do processo de compilação possa validar aquilo ou usar para alguma operação mais complexa. É uma forma de deixar a linguagem mais poderosa, e principalmente com mais capacidade de dar segurança.

De fato se quiser saber mais pode consultar a [documentação do SAL](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2015/code-quality/using-sal-annotations-to-reduce-c-cpp-code-defects?view=vs-2015WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).